# A particular regex is not validated correctly using Angular form Validation

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, validation

For my project I am trying to add a particular validation pattern/regular expression to an input field. Til now, each of the expressions I used were working fine.

Right now I came up with the following expression:

`[^-+,.]*\d+`

Meaning: the input should not contain any `-`, `+`, `,` or `.`. Also it should contain one or more decimal number. (0-9) (can be tested with https://regex101.com/)

**my.component.ts**

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  employeeNumber: [employeeNumber, [Validators.pattern(/^[^-+,.]*\d+$/)]]
});
```

The regular expression does work as expected. It is allowed to set any of the forbidden characters in the input field. The validation does not fail. It does when I try another regular expression.

Strings containing one (or more) of those invalid characters are seen as `valid`. 
Examples:
`25.64`, `-135,46`, `++9035`.

How does it come that this particular regex is not working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What number do you call "decimal"? Your regex allows any text like `abra*§cadabra123` now as `[^-+,.]*` matches *any* 0+ chars other than `-`, `+`, `,` and `.`. Did you mean to only pass a float or int like strings? `Validators.pattern('\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?')` / `Validators.pattern(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/)`?

Comment: The input is already limited to `number` so the user cannot type in chars. But as `-+,.e` are related to numbers, those can be typed in the input field.

Comment: So what do you want to pass and what to fail? Supply some example strings please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that the input was of type `number`. Regular expressions like this can only be added to input fields that are of the default type `text`.